# How do I make a web server to make timed multiple choice tests?

Tags: python, web-applications, haskell, clojure, lisp

I'd like to make a webapp that asks people multiple choice questions, and times how long they take to answer.

I'd like those who want to, to be able to make accounts, and to store the data for how well they've done and how their performance is increasing.

I've never written any sort of web app before, although I'm a good programmer and understand how http works.

I'm assuming (without evidence) that it's better to use a 'framework' than to hack something together from scratch, and I'd appreciate advice on which framework people think would be most appropriate.

I hope that it will prove popular, but would rather get something working than spend time at the start worrying about scaling. Is this sane?

And I'd like to be able to develop and test this on my own machine, and then deploy it to a virtual server or some other hosting solution.

I'd prefer to use a language like Clojure or Lisp or Haskell, but if the advantages of using, say, Python or Ruby would outweigh the fact that I'd enjoy it more in a more maths-y language, then I like both of those too.

I probably draw the line at perl, but if perl or even something like Java or C have compelling advantages then I'm quite happy with them too. They just don't seem appropriate for this sort of thing.

Comment: I don't think you want to us a functional language to write a web server, though I've seen it done in some form.  If you like Python you'll want to try one of the countless simple Pythonic web frameworks. I won't name any, however, as that way leads to a flamewar. I fear this isn't likely to be constructive. You'll also likely want some JavaScript on the front-end. For throwing together a nice web frontend quickly take a look at [Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/) and [jQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/)

Comment: Curses, recommendations for particular frameworks is exactly what I want. Can you point me to some flamewars that I can mine for evidence?

Comment: Not particularly, but if that's really what you want I recommend [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/).  It's pretty trivial to get up and running with.

Comment: Good. Thanks. My intuition tells me that Flask is the best one to use for Python. If that's also the recommendation from python people then I can weigh that against the best recommendations from the Clojure and Haskell folks and I'm done.

Comment: @Iguananaut You've claimed you're not starting a flamewar, straight after hitting out at functional programming! There's more than one web framework in haskell, for example, which benefits from extremely lightweight threads so is actually quite a good place to start on a webserver that scales well. However, he (intelligently) asked for a framework, not to write one from scratch. Read for example, about the use of [haskell behind the scences](http://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/uved7/waldo_the_haskell_powered_codebase_behind_xkcds/) at [xkcd.com](http://xkcd.com/).

Comment: @AndrewC I stand corrected, and spent some time exploring a couple of Haskell and Clojure web frameworks that were quite elegant.  I certainly would never have ruled out functional programming for specialized high-concurrency web servers, but there are more simpler to use general purpose web frameworks than I was aware of :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can recommend to start with [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/). It's very easy.

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

with templates (`jinja`,`mako`, etc.) you can easily create dynamic web pages: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/templating/

An easy solution for your time calculation problem would probably be to put the server time in the form for the question and calculate the delta when getting the response back.

**EDIT** : Oh, and another thing, you can deploy a Flask app relatively easily on [Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python), which is a free cloud application platform.

Comment: Heroku is free? I thought it was pay-for. I'll investigate. If so then that just wins for deployment, I think. That still leaves a choice between Python and Clojure though.

Comment: Oh, ok, free for the first '75 dyno-hours per month'. What on earth does that mean? I hope it means 'free to play with and as long as not many people use it, but you have to pay us if it gets popular.' Anyone know? And what sort of usage is 75 dyno-hours? Do language and framework make a big difference there, or is it more about how often it gets woken up?

Comment: @JohnLawrenceAspden it's `750` dyno-hours per month and it means that if you use 1 dyno it's completely free because (24 * 31 = 744 hours / mo) and if you are using 2 dynos you have 1/2 month of free operation and so on. So start with one dyno and see if it suits you.

Comment: Sweet! So they'll give you a free virtual machine to try it out on? That looks great. I'll try it. Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 5):

> I'd prefer to use a language like Clojure or Lisp or Haskell

If you're comfortable with Haskell your option is [Yesod](http://www.yesodweb.com/) (I love it).

If not, what is your priority?

- learn, enjoy and productivity -> then your option is Haskell + Yesod.
- productivity quickly -> Python, Ruby, ...

Answer (score 1):

When the server-side creates the form, encode an hidden field with the timestamp of the request, so when the users POSTs his form, you can see the time difference.

How to implement that is up to you, which server you have available, and several other factors.

Answer (score 1):

As far as Haskell web frameworks go, I would also recommend [Happstack](http://www.happstack.com), but Yesod is itself fine software with perhaps a stronger support base. In either case, do not be talked out of Haskell; I wrote my own blog engine (presently running [The Ambulatory Sesquipedalian](http://blog.iansturdy.com)) using Happstack and found no reason to believe that Haskell is unsuited to these tasks. Local testing followed by deployment to a VPS is natural for both--they will run on about anything you can install the Haskell Platform on.

As far as the timing goes: however you implement it, be careful that users cannot fake times. Since you seem to be committed to user accounts, I would recommend having users check out tests, leaving a timestamped entry in their profile of the time they started the test and checking against that when they submit their answers. Solutions that use client-side state are also possible, but remember to protect against client manipulation of data (editing cookies or manually constructing POSTs with hidden fields altered)--you would probably need to somehow encrypt the time (it could still be altered, but not to a user-chosen value).